# ¿Como encontrar mas de 2 dígitos después de un decimal en Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-19c

Buen dia amigos, me surgió un problema ya que en unos campos me arroja por ejemplo de estos montos 392.90962209, lo que quiero hacer es una consulta donde me traiga solo de esos registros, hay alguna función en oracle sql donde me traiga solo esos registros?

Por ejm, así me llega:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí aparecen poquitos y los alcancé a detectar, espero y puedan ayudar por favor en brindarme algunos ejemplos, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios, muchas gracias.

Comment: En qué formato están definidas esas columnas?

Comment: Hola amigo, están en numéricos.

Comment: Pasó que desde un archivo de texto se pobló de esa forma con ese numero largo

Answer (score 3):

Puedes comparar el valor contra un valor truncado.

```
SELECT *
FROM MiTabla
WHERE SALDO_ANTERIOR > TRUNC( SALDO_ANTERIOR, 2);
```

Comment: Hola Luis Cazares, intenté de esa forma como lo pusiste pero no tuve exito :( mas que nada lo que se requiere es solo traer los que tienen muchos digitos despues del punto, para que posteriormente en el archivo origen los cambien directamente

Comment: Lo siento, pero el decir "no tuve éxito", no me dice nada. Te sugiero que veas como publicar un [example].